# Best method for text parsing androidK

Tags: java, android, xml, android-ndk

I am trying to write a program in android that does a lot of string and xml parsing.

I need suggestion of which way to go :

1. Use JNI and implement parsing in C++ and use C++ xml SAX parsing (Android - NDk)
2. Go with java and parse xml with SAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered a server-side component that could do the majority of the parsing, which then sends a stream to devices that is significantly easier for the device to parse? You could present a web interface in addition to a mobile interface. It would be easier to setup subscriptions for which you could charge a fee if you someday decided to.

Comment: This was actually my first thought, I might end up with that itself, but really wanted to know if there was a better way to do it on the device itself.

Comment: Using the server side component is good for implementing , I also went through a lot of forums and articles. The NDK is particularly useful when there is a lot of CPU bound operations and less memory involved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest option 2. 
It may not be worth it to go with the complexity of NDK just for the parsing purpose.

Comment: yeah by JNI (option 1) i mean the NDK

Comment: how will be the speed trade-off's? the amount of data i would like to process is quite big ( Lets say 50 - 100 Rss feeds) i would not be just parsing the rss xml and store it, but do more operations on the data in the posts.